# How to parse an already double quoted JSON data in Objective-C?

Tags: ios, objective-c, json

how to parse an already **double quoted** json data

eg: JSON Received - "first_name" = Noah;

This is the code I used.

```
//"first_name" = Noah; 
NSString *name=[result valueForKeyPath:@"first_name"]; 
if ([result.grantedPermissions containsObject:@"email"]) { 
    if ([FBSDKAccessToken currentAccessToken]) { 
       [[[FBSDKGraphRequest alloc] initWithGraphPath:@"me" parameters:nil] startWithCompletionHandler:^(FBSDKGraphRequestConnection *connection, id result, NSError *error) { 
           NSString *gender=[result valueForKeyPath:@"gender"];
       }
    }
}
```

Comment: Show more of your code. Show how `result` was obtained.

Comment: >"first_name" = Noah;
   >NSString *name=[result valueForKeyPath:@"first_name"];
>if ([result.grantedPermissions containsObject:@"email"])
            >{
>if ([FBSDKAccessToken currentAccessToken]) {
>[[[FBSDKGraphRequest alloc] initWithGraphPath:@"me" parameters:nil]
                     >startWithCompletionHandler:^(FBSDKGraphRequestConnection >*connection, id result, NSError *error) {

> NSString *gender=[result valueForKeyPath:@"gender"];

Comment: Put the code in your question so people can read it.

Comment: You added the wrong code. Show the code that actually populates `result`. And explain what issue you are having with the code you posted.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use triple quote

```
NSString *name=[result valueForKeyPath:@"""first_name"""]; 
if ([result.grantedPermissions containsObject:@"email"]) { 
   if ([FBSDKAccessToken currentAccessToken]) { 
   [[[FBSDKGraphRequest alloc] initWithGraphPath:@"me" parameters:nil] startWithCompletionHandler:^(FBSDKGraphRequestConnection *connection, id result, NSError *error) {NSString *gender=[result valueForKeyPath:@"gender"];
      }
   }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

When you use the `description` method of NSDictionary to display a dictionary (which you do implicitly when you do NSLog, eg), the data is displayed like this:

1. The whole dictionary is surrounded by the `{ }` characters.
2. Key/value pairs are shown as `<key> = <value>`, with `;` separating pairs.
3. If a key or value is an NSString it's displayed as follows:

   - If a string is purely alphanumeric it is displayed without quotes.
   - If a string contains blanks or non-alphabetic characters (such as `_`) it is displayed surrounded by double quotes (`"`).
   - If a string contains non-ASCII characters, those characters are displayed as Unicode escape sequences.
4. Note that NSNumber values are displayed as plain numbers, without any distinguishing characters, so it's pretty much impossible to tell whether `123` is an NSString or an NSNumber by simply looking at the NSLog.

So there's generally no need to be concerned about a key or value displayed as, eg, `"first_name"` -- it's just an ordinary NSString.